# Format mismatch while converting the string to datetime format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

My aim is to convert a string into datetime format. The string format is `2020-10-02 09:00:00.000`
I tried below methods and both are giving me a format mismatch error.

```
timerangestart = "2020-10-02 09:00:00.000"
timerangestart = timerangestart[:-4]
my_time = datetime.strptime(timerangestart, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

timerangestart = "2020-10-02 09:00:00.000"
timerangestart = timerangestart + "000"
my_time = datetime.strptime(timerangestart, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

ValueError: time data '2020-10-02 09:00:00' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: You could have used `datetime.fromisoformat` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `%y` is wrong. It should be `%Y`.

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

timerangestart = "2020-10-02 09:00:00.000"
timerangestart = timerangestart[:-4]
my_time = datetime.strptime(timerangestart, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(my_time)

timerangestart = "2020-10-02 09:00:00.000"
timerangestart = timerangestart + "000"
my_time = datetime.strptime(timerangestart, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

print(my_time)
```

Output:

```
2020-10-02 09:00:00
2020-10-02 09:00:00
```

[Here's](https://strftime.org/) a handy reference table of `strftime()` formatting.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat